# Image from resource file not loading in Qt

Tags: qt, qimage, qt-resource

I'm trying to insert an image to my program via resource file, which is like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>green.png</file>
        <file>other files</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and when I'm trying to load it using `QImage` or `QPixmap`, like:

```
QImage *green = new QImage(":/green.png");
if(green->isNull()) qDebug("null");
```

I always see that `null` message, indicating that I'm doing something wrong.

One solution may be using absolute path like:

```
<file>C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project\\green.png</file>
```

which works of course, but I'd prefer implement it using resource file.

Comment: Where is your resource file located?

Comment: all code/resource files are in C:\Users\...\project

Comment: Odd. Your exact example works for me. I'm using Linux + Qt 4.8.6. Try one of Qt's examples ('System Tray Icon Example' contains qrc file).

Comment: Works also on Win 8.1 and Qt 5.4

Comment: Works for me. Do you get any error messages from rcc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem would be solved if your `png` files are located in the same folder as `.pro`, `.qrc`, and `.cpp` files of your project.

Usually it is convenient to put all images to special sub-folder, **Resources** for example. And your `.qrc` file would look like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
         <file>Resources/green.png</file>
        <file>Resources/other files</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And you can use it in your `.cpp` file like this:

```
QImage *green = new QImage(":/Resources/green.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to how you can add a resource file `.qrc` to your project:

- **Image folder must be contained inside of the project folder**
- Right-click on the project file
- Add New
- Qt -> Qt Resource File -> press Choose -> name your file -> Finish.
- After opening your `.qrc` file, press Add -> Add Prefix -> change prefix name if you want.
- Add -> Add File -> and choose your images.
- Go to `mainwindow.cpp` file and use the images from your `.qrc` file as follows:

> ```
> ui->play->setIcon(QIcon(":/Playericons/icons8-pause-30.png"));
> ```

in my case, the image folder is called `Playericons`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to run qmake after adding the resource file?